# How to use Seekbar value as int variable?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make the "a" variable to take the value of the seekbar and use it for the "sleep" param. Now, 'a' is 100. Can this be done with int? What I want: a = the value of the SeekBar as int value instead of 100. I have tried different methods but didn't have any luck. I have also attached the xml code.

```
public class Blink1 extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler ;
ConstraintLayout blink1 ;
int i = 0;
int colors[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override


        public void run () {
        blink1.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
        if(i==1){
            i=0;
        }
        else i++;

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blink1);

    handler = new Handler();
    blink1 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.blink2);

    final int a;
    a=100;

    Thread myTread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        sleep(a);
                        handler.post(runnable);

                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        myTread.start();
    }
    }
```

the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/blink2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.studios.minimal.blink.Blink1">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar7"
    android:max="1000"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.903" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SeekBar seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar7);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                a=seekBar.getProgress();
            }
        });
```